# Applying for a Schengen visa in Paris?

Tags: visas, schengen, france

I am currently having a Schengen visa (short stay visa: 90 days). My visa was issued by the French embassy, multi-entries, valid for 1 year, with a maximum stay of 90 days. And it will expire next month. Currently, I am staying in Paris.

I want to ask:

Is it possible to ask for a new Schengen visa (short terms, etc.) in Paris when my visa is expired? Or Do I have to leave France to be able to ask for new visa from another country that is not a Schengen country?

If yes, could you please point me the information (for example: website, or who should I need to contact to get the information, etc.)

Comment: Where would your next trip be to - France, or elsewhere in the Schengen zone?

Comment: I want to stay in France, most of the time.

Comment: I think the risk is that they'll think you've in effect moved to France on a short stay visa... Any chance you might qualify for a more long term permit?

Comment: I am a student in France. I can ask for a student visa or a scientific visa (if needed). But I am wondering is am I able to ask such visas if I am having a short term visa, also am I able to ask it in Paris? and where I could do that?

Comment: And how long for it to commit, and at that time, my visa is expire am I able to continue to stay in France while I wait for the result?

Comment: Fairly sure that if you're a full-time student in France, then you shouldn't be on a short term visit visa...

Comment: It is a complicated situation. I am a student of France (PhD. student), but I was doing my study in China. And I came to France to visit my professor, and in that time because of the time reason we asked for visit visa. But now I need to stay another 3 months to be able to have enough time to complete my study here.

Comment: If you look at the [France Diplomatie page on visas](http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/en/coming-to-france/getting-a-visa/article/what-type-to-apply-for), it suggests that short bits of study are fine on a short stay schengen visa, but prolonged study needs to be on a long stay visa

Comment: But my question is am I able to apply for a new visa in France, Paris? because in that time my current visa is expire, am I able to stay in Paris in a waiting time?

Answer (score 6):

Most countries do not allow visitors to extend or replace their visa when actually staying in the country. There are of course a few exceptions, but you must apply for a French visa in your usual country of residence.

Quoting from "[France Diplomatie Visa FAQs](http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/en/coming-to-france/getting-a-visa/article/faq-visas)":

> **I am present in France and my visa has expired. Can I send my passport
>   to the consulate in my usual country of residence to extend my stay in
>   France?**
>
> No. You must return to your usual country of residence to submit a new
>   visa application.

Answer (score 3):

As Tor-Einar Jarnbjo correctly pointed out (+1), Schengen visas cannot generally be obtained from within France (or, in fact, anywhere in the Schengen area). It's sometimes (but not always) possible to apply for a *residence permit* from within a Schengen member state. In France, [there are some exceptions](http://vosdroits.service-public.fr/particuliers/F2231.xhtml) (and as a PhD student, you *might* qualify for one) but you generally need to obtain a long-stay visa from a French consulate abroad before applying for a student residence permit (i.e. you can't apply for it if you are visiting the country on a short-stay visa).

Furthermore, Schengen visas (and other French visas) should be obtained from the consulate competent for your usual place of residence. In practice, the requirements vary and you might be able to skirt the rules but in principle it means that merely going to the UK, Turkey or some other place outside the Schengen area is not enough, you also need to be a resident there to apply for a Schengen visa. Otherwise, you might have to go to your last country of residence.

In any case, the relevant authority to contact within France for all immigration matters is the *préfecture* of your place of residence (in Paris, the *préfecture de police*).